# How can I fix idle-python3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-idle

I have a big problem with python idle. If I try to run for example 
sudo apt-get `install apache2` I get this error:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
And it is not just for apache, it happens for all the apps that I try to install with sudo apt-get install
```

I've tried to unistall idle, but it doesen't work

If I run

```
sudo apt-fix broken install
```

I get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/idlelib/CREDITS.txt', which is also in package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.8-1+xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

is

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle:
idle depends on idle-python3.6; however:
Package idle-python3.6 is not installed.


dpkg: error processing package idle (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
idle
```

The output of  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

If I try to reinstall with the command:

```
 sudo apt install idle-python3.6
```

I get this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.york0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/idlelib/CREDITS.txt', which is also in package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.8-1+xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.8-1~18.04.york0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: This is an ubuntu package manager problem, not a programming problem, and off-topic here.  The message for the ubuntu tag says to use askubuntu.com. I think part of the problem you have run into is that some linux distribution put parts or all of _tkinter, tkinter, idlelib, and turtle for python x.y.z into a separate installation package from python x.y.z itself.  And tcl/tk is also a separate package, or maybe included in the base distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the dependency problem due to bad configuration.

You can refer the ubuntu forum which had similar problem :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install